# update mysql date random between two dates

Tags: mysql, date, random

How do I update in phpmyadmin SQL box a date field formatted as 13-01-1980 with random date between 2 dates, such as, any day between 01-01-1990 and 01-01-1995 ?

I read many answers here on stackoverflow and elsewhere but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You would just use date arithmetic with `rand()`:

```
select date_add(date('1990-01-01'),
                interval cast(rand() * datediff('1995-01-01', '1990-01-01') as int) day)
```

EDIT:

For an `update`, it would be essentially the same logic:

```
update t
    set col2 = date_add(date('1990-01-01'),
                interval cast(rand() * datediff('1995-01-01', '1990-01-01') as int) day)
    where col = 'abc';
```

Comment: thank you much Gordon. How do I use this within the syntax of an update table mysql command? e.g. Update TABLE  where col="abc" set col2="select date_add(date('1990-01-01'),
                interval cast(rand() * datediff('1995-01-01', '1990-01-01') as int) day)";